# I provide password in envoy script but it prompts to enter password manually

Tags: laravel-envoy

With laravel 5.8  envoy command I deploy on remote server and I set  password in command line, like:

```
envoy run Hostels2Deploy --lardeployer_password=111 --app_version=0.105a
```

and envoy file:

```
@setup
    $server_login_user= 'lardeployer';
    $lardeployer_password = isset($lardeployer_password) ? $lardeployer_password : "Not Defined";
@endsetup

@servers(['dev' => $server_login_user.':'.$lardeployer_password.'@NNN.NN.NNN.N'])


@task('clean_old_releases')
    echo "Step # 81";
    echo 'The password is: {{ $lardeployer_password }}';
    echo 'The $server_login_user is: {{ $server_login_user }}';
    echo "Step # 00 app_version ::{{ $app_version }}";

    cd {{ $release_number_dir }}
    # php artisan envoy:delete-old-versions  Hostels2Deployed
@endtask

@macro('Hostels2Deploy',['on'=>'dev'])
    clean_old_releases
@endmacro
```

With credentials in @servers block I expected I will not have to enter password manually, but in command line I see prompt to enter
password. I output $server_login_user and  $lardeployer_password vars and they have valid values.

Which is valid path ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a decision with ssh keys in /home/user/.ssh/config of my OS to add line :

```
Host laravelserver
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    HostName NNN.NN.NNN.N
    Port 22
    User lardeployer
```

and in envoy file to connect to this server like :

```
@servers(['dev' => ['laravelserver'] )
```

Aslo on remote user in file authorized_keys lardeployer's public key must be added.

and restart the sevice :

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```